# React select v2 css issues and compatibility with react-virtualised select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have upgraded by react-select to version 2 beta, to be able to include grouped selects. I am facing few issues here,

1) Importing react-select.css throws an error that file is not found
`import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';`
2) Also, i would want to know if react-virtualized-select is compatible with this version. I have tried to implement this, firstly the css breaks as the react-select.css is not loaded but it does show me the options and is quite fast , but the onchange function doesnt seem to be working. ( I am using the grouped select feature)

Any inputs on these issues will be useful, Thanks

Comment: What version of React are you using ?

Comment: i am using version 16.1

Comment: Can you please in your node_modules whether you have React-select folder?